# How to neaten a long built in template tag in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do you neaten a long template tag like this:

```
<td>{{ membership.is_project_manager|yesno:"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>,<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>"|safe  }}</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are duplicating a lot of code in the `yesno` tag. All you really need is `glyphicon-ok` or `glyphicon-remove`. The rest is displayed all the time.

You could change it to:

```
<td><span class='glyphicon {{ membership.is_project_manager|yesno:"glyphicon-ok,glyphicon-remove" }}'></span></td>
```

You could also move the `glyphicon-` part out of the `yesno` tag if you want.

Personally I might find a simple if tag more readable, but that's a personal preference.

```
<td><span class='glyphicon {% if membership.is_project_manager %}glyphicon-ok{% else %}glyphicon-remove{% endif %}'></span></td>
```

If you found yourself writing this code a lot then you could write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) that returns `glyphicon-ok` or `glyphicon-remove`. That could simplify the template down to something like:

```
<td><span class='glyphicon {% glyphicon_class membership %}'></span></td>
```